# Does an Azeri visa cost $100 for an Australian citizen no matter how they get it?

Tags: visas, australian-citizens, azerbaijan

I just noticed [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens#Non-EU) that as an Australian citizen I can get a visa for Azerbaijan upon arrival but for the huge price of *$100*.

So is that price only for the on-arrival issue of the visa or is it also if I apply for it at an embassy before my trip?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Ministry of Foreign Afairs](http://mfa.gov.az/eng/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=609&Itemid=1) of Azerbaijan I think it should only cost *$40 USD* if you get it in advance.

Comment: Wow that's really confusing. It also mentions a "touristic visa" which is only $20 but you must have a "travel voucher", which it doesn't say anything else about. Plus there is something about a 2 manat fee for "granting visa on the basis of invitation letter". Then [it links to a PDF file](http://mfa.gov.az/images/stories/Consular%20issues/new%20visa%20fees%20.pdf) which says it's $58 for a single entry visa for an Australian!

Comment: Yes I wasn't really sure which of this preconditions apply for you, so I just linked the root site ;)

Comment: If it's this cheap then I really want to go! I feel more questions are in order...